# pandas drop diffrent rows with differing column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["a","b","c","d","e", "e"], 'col2': [1,3,3,2,6,6], 'col3': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})` that looks like

Input:

```
     col1 col2 col3
    0   a   1   1
    1   b   3   2
    2   c   3   3
    3   d   2   4
    4   e   6   5
    5   e   6   6
```

I would like to remove rows from "col1" that share a common value in "col2" except values that are the same i.e. letter "e". I would like it to be where only one value in "col1" can = a unique one in "col2" The expected output would look something like...

Output:

```
     col1 col2 col3
    0   a   1   1
    3   d   2   4
    4   e   6   5
    5   e   6   6
```

What would be the process of doing this?

Comment: So rows 1 and 2 are gone because col2 == 3 on both AND col1 is different?

Comment: Can you share your code attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you described, I understood as follows:

1. If two rows have same values in `col2`, they both are dropped.
2. If two rows have same value in `col2` but have same values in `col1`, you want to keep them.
3. All other rows which do not fall in above two categories, you want to keep.

This can be achieved as:

```
df[np.logical_or(~df.duplicated('col2', keep = False),df.duplicated('col1', keep = False)) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following :

```
df[df.col1.duplicated(keep=False) | ~df.col2.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Output

```
| col1   |   col2 |   col3 |
|:-------|-------:|-------:|
| a      |      1 |      1 |
| d      |      2 |      4 |
| e      |      6 |      5 |
| e      |      6 |      6 |
```